# What is the alternative to IntrinsicHeight in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code in `bottomNavigationBar`"

```
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                icon: Text(
                  "QR",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              VerticalDivider(
                color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline.color,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

And the code works as expected.

[image]

If I remove IntrinsicHeight widget, the divider goes all the way across all screen.

[image]

The reason I want an alternative is because in the documentation of `IntrinsicHeight` it says: 
`This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible.`

What would be the cheap alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for "a cheap way to have the row fit the min height of dynamic content", then there are none.

The cheap solution is, to have a fixed height on the `Row` – typically by wrapping it in `SizedBox`:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 42,
  child: Row(...),
)
```

This works well if the content has a fixed height. But it won't if the height is dynamic.

Comment: Alright. I was wandering what is the min size of the BottomAppBar, tahn I can put it like that and keep it always in bounds.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you could either use SizedBox with height=48 (this is the [default height of the IconButton](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/47457) widget) or avoid using VerticalDivider and draw it by adding a left border to the share icon.

```
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                left: Divider.createBorderSide(
                  context,
                  color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline.color,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter it might seem counter-intuitive, but when most widgets are given **bounded** constraints they try to fill the **whole** (bounded) space allowed, whereas when given **unbounded** constraints (set to INFINITY) they only take the required space (their **intrinsic** size). So to make a widget have its intrinsic size one can try wrapping it with `UnconstrainedBox`.

But it might be problematic in your case, because you are using a `Row`, and its height should not be unbounded..

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a widget in a Container with a *specific height* that's  the alternative of Intrinsic Height.